# Observer Design Pattern in web application

Tags: java, facebook, spring-mvc, design-patterns

sorry for english.Currently i am working on social media project in spring with like and comment functionality and i want to use Observer Design Pattern.suppose one user likes or comment video then should be reflect on all user at a time like facebook.
so,
If one user likes a video then How will i update all active user.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is If one user likes a video then How will i update all active user.

Comment: You mean if user A is currently on the video page and another user B likes the video, you want to update the user A page with user B's like?

Comment: yes rob.same as facebook

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an observable class, say Notifier.java
2. Maintain a list of users (user.java) in Notifier class
3. Upon every user object creation, add it to list.
4. User class must contain a eventNotification method.
5. On like or comment, Notifier class must call eventNotification method of all user objects in the list.

Comment: thanks Dinil but How will i create the object of user(you mean user login records) and update the view page of all Observer User.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java you can use the java.util.Observable and java.util.Observer interfaces

```
class User implements Observer {

    String name;
    public String getName() {return name;}

    public void update(Observable obs, Object x) {
      if (obs instanceof Video) {
        Video v = (Video)obs;
        String user = (String)x;
        System.out.println("User " + user.getName() + " liked video" + v.getName());
      }
    }
  }


  class Video extends Observable {

    String name;
    public String getName() {return name;}

    public Video(String name) {this.name = name; }

    public void like(User user) {
        // Notify observers of change
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(user);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] av) {
    Video v = new Video("video1");
    User user1 = new User();
    User user2 = new User();
    User user3 = new User();
    v.addObserver(user1);
    v.addObserver(user2);
    v.addObserver(user3);
    v.like(user1);
  }
```

Comment: thanks rob.I know the concept of Observer Design pattern. actually i want to implement in web application.any idea